# Svelte store : work in layout but not in page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In a sveltekit application, I'm using the store to save a user email after success logged in. The store seems to work in the layout but not in pages. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong ? Moreover, I noticed that when I save the file in VS Code the HMR makes the store in +page.svelte work, but when I manually reload the page the store goes back to undefined.
Thanks for your help !

Here's my stores.js file :

```
// lib/stores.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const userEmail = writable(null);
```

Here's the layout where I manage the connection (with Firebase) and where I set the store value :

```
// +layout.svelte
<script>
    import { userEmail } from "$lib/stores.js";

    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { auth } from "$lib/firebase/fbInit";

    onMount(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
            if (user) {
                await userEmail.set(user.email);
                console.log($userEmail + " is connected"); // ----- The store works here and shows the user email
            } else {
                console.log("no user connected");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here's the page example where I want to access the store value :

```
// examplepage/+page.svelte
<script>
    import { userEmail } from "$lib/stores.js";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    onMount(async () => {
        console.log("Email in store", $userEmail); // ----- But not working here : shows undefined (but the layout console.log still shows the right user email yet)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't really use `await` in front of `userEmail.set(...)`, since that method doesn't return a Promise. Also, in the page, you only log the user's email when the user come to that page. You understand that the page won't log the email each time it changes, right? For that you need to subscribe to the store using the `subscribe()` method.

Comment: @PeppeL-G: You generally don't need to (or should) subscribe, `$`-syntax takes care of that, ***if*** used reactively.

Comment: @brunnerh, is it possible to use the `$`-syntax in `onMount()`? Because, as you wrote, the code in your suggested answer will also run on server-side rendering. I would say using `onMount()` (and `subscribe()`) would be more suitable otherwise, but I can be wrong.

Comment: @PeppeL-G: You can use `$`-syntax in `onMount`. Internally it just uses `subscribe()`. The difference is that if you use `subscribe` yourself, you should also unsubscribe to prevent leak issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the page/layout distinction.

In the layout you do something when an event happens that actually influences the auth state.

On the page you log *once on page load*. If the page loads before the auth state change happens, you will get nothing in the store.

If you want to do something once the store has been updated, use a reactive statement like this, for example:

```js
$: if ($userEmail) {
  console.log('user e-mail is:', $userEmail);
}
```

Use in markup, e.g. in an `{#if $userEmail}` will be reactive as well.

Also, you should *avoid* global stores (e.g. instances like this one that are exported directly from a module) if they can be evaluated during server-side rendering. The store would be shared between all requests and if it is no cleaned up correctly might contain state belonging to a different user.

The same is of course true for *any* global state.

Would recommend the use of a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#setcontext) instead, they can also include stores to transport reactivity.

Comment: Works perfectly and things are clearer. Thank you very much !!